# MySQL select where Uppercase follows Lowercase

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table witch contains many Names formatted like:

```
Max.Example
```

I wanted to replace the . with a Space but I accidently replaced it with nothing so they are all like: `MaxMuster`

I cant restore a backup or roll back.
The only way thad I found would be to insert a Space everywhere a Capital Letter is after a normal one. But what is the command for that?

Comment: Will there only be one dot?

Comment: @yvytty there is no difference. Doesn't matter. There is only one column.

Comment: The fields are normal Text fields and there are maybe other dots but it would not be a problem if the get replaced with spaces. The Table has also other columns but i just have a problem with the names.

Comment: Is it an option to install the regular expression module? https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp In that case it's fairly trivial to fix, otherwise not impossible but a bit of a pain.

Comment: @WoLpH I would like it with just with normal SQL. But if there is no other way.

Comment: Can you create functions in your mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer based on the Bruteforce script from Mark Bannister

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMN = ltrim(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(COLUMN
                      ,'zA','z A')
                     ,'zB','z B')
                     ,'zC','z C')
                     ,'zD','z D')
                     ,'zE','z E')
                     ,'zF','z F')
                     ,'zG','z G')
                     ,'zH','z H')
                     ,'zI','z I')
                     ,'zJ','z J')
                     ,'zK','z K')
                     ,'zL','z L')
                     ,'zM','z M')
                     ,'zN','z N')
                     ,'zO','z O')
                     ,'zP','z P')
                     ,'zQ','z Q')
                     ,'zR','z R')
                     ,'zS','z S')
                     ,'zT','z T')
                     ,'zU','z U')
                     ,'zV','z V')
                     ,'zW','z W')
                     ,'zX','z X')
                     ,'zY','z Y')
                     ,'zZ','z Z')
            );
```

This works for everything.

```
MaxExample = Max Example
MaxExampleTest = Max Example Test
MaxExampleTestTT = Max Example Test TT
```

Just repeat this 26 times for all letters.

Comment: This is both really fast and works flawlessly. Not the neatest, but does the job with quality and speed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this procedure ...

```
create procedure updateName()
begin
  declare cnt, len, val, flag int;
  declare newName, oldName varchar(30);
  select count(*) into cnt from tbl;
  set cnt =cnt-1;
  while cnt >= 0 do
     set flag=0;
     select details into oldName from tbl limit cnt, 1;
     select length(oldname) into len;
     while flag=0 and len > 0 do
        select ascii(substring(oldname, len)) into val;
        if val < 90 then 
          select concat(substring(oldname, 1, len-1), ' ', substring(oldname,len)) into newname;
          update tbl set details = newName where details  = oldname;
          set flag=1;
        end if;
        set len = len - 1;
     end while;
     set cnt = cnt-1;
  end while;

end//
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19929/1)**

### ***EDIT***

For multiple caps char
To solve the prob of multiple caps char

```
create procedure updateName()
begin
  declare cnt, len, val, flag int;
  declare newName, oldName varchar(30);
  select count(*) into cnt from tbl;
  set cnt =cnt-1;
  while cnt >= 0 do
     set flag=0;
     select details into oldName from tbl limit cnt, 1;
     select length(oldname) into len;
     while len > 1 do
        select ascii(substring(oldname, len)) into val;
        if val < 90 then 
          select concat(substring(oldname, 1, len-1), ' ', substring(oldname,len)) into newname;
          update tbl set details = newName where details  = oldname;
          set oldname=newname;
        end if;
        set len = len - 1;
     end while;
     set cnt = cnt-1;
  end while;

end//
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceee3/1)**

Take a back up of your table before running this proc..

Hope this helps....

Comment: Like your Way but it breaks when the name has Multible Capital Letters for example: `AsminFiddleTest` is then `AsminFiddle Test` I think i need to use Mark Bannister Brute Force Method.

Comment: @user2436057 Try the edited one it works for any number of caps char. I have just removed the flag to stop at 1 char.. check the edited answer..

Comment: Thanks but IT Still Has a Problem with double Capitals I think BruteForce is the best Way

Comment: 'AsminFiddleTestTT' gives 'Asmin Fiddle Test T T' not 'Asmin Fiddle Test TT'

Comment: This proc will split whenever it finds a caps char and this behavior will be even in the brute force approach...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute force approach:

```
select ltrim(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(myColumn
                     ,'A',' A')
                     ,'B',' B')
                     ,'C',' C')
                     ,'D',' D')
                     ,'E',' E')
                     ,'F',' F')
                     ,'G',' G')
                     ,'H',' H')
                     ,'I',' I')
                     ,'J',' J')
                     ,'K',' K')
                     ,'L',' L')
                     ,'M',' M')
                     ,'N',' N')
                     ,'O',' O')
                     ,'P',' P')
                     ,'Q',' Q')
                     ,'R',' R')
                     ,'S',' S')
                     ,'T',' T')
                     ,'U',' U')
                     ,'V',' V')
                     ,'W',' W')
                     ,'X',' X')
                     ,'Y',' Y')
                     ,'Z',' Z')
            )
from myTable
```

Comment: This is good, i Like it. I now just need to fix it so it doesn't make a Space at the Front and somhow thad ist doesent put a Space when the name is 'MaxExampleMISTER' or so.

Comment: @user2436057: The LTRIM at the start should take care of the Leading space, but handling multiple sequential capital letters might be more problematic - I suggest using regexp to identify them, and to update them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach. Beef up UNION query upto the max length of you column. It has room for improvement too.

```
select details, group_concat(t2.c1) as new_value  from (

Select details, 
case 
  when n = 1 then substr(details,n,1)
  when ascii(substr(details,n,1)) between ascii ('A') and ascii ('Z') 
      then concat (' ', substr(details,n,1))
  else substr(details,n,1)
end as c1

,n
FROM tbl, 

  (select 1 as n union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6 union all
select 7 union all
select 8 union all
select 9 union all
select 10
    )
  as tbl_1 

where substr(details,n,1) is not null

) as t2
group by details
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor start would be to use REGEXP to check for a letter followed by capital letter (moving that to WHERE):

```
SELECT field REGEXP BINARY '[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}' FROM test
```

but again, it is not a full answer, more just an idea.

Comment: OK it shows me if there is one or not but it doesen't dedect if there are multible cases witch happen in my Table.

Answer (score 0):

A horribly brute force way to do this might help in this situation.  Use a giant case to find where the first capital letter is:

```
select (case when pos is null then field
             else concat(substr(field, 1, pos - 1), '.', substr(field, pos))
from (select (case when ascii(substr(col, 2, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 2
                   when ascii(substr(col, 3, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 3
                   when ascii(substr(col, 4, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 4
                   when ascii(substr(col, 5, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 5
                   when ascii(substr(col, 6, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 6
                   when ascii(substr(col, 7, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 7
                   when ascii(substr(col, 8, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 8
                   when ascii(substr(col, 9, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 9
                   when ascii(substr(col, 10, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z') then 10
              end) as pos, field
      from t
     ) t
```

I'm not sure if you need the corresponding `update` statement, or just the logic for finding the position for the period.